# Rails 3, Paperclip - Custom Interpolations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, interpolation

I've been having some troubles making custom Interpolation, gone through every example I could find on web, but no matter what I did, had no success.
At the moment I have this:

Model

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:img_name-:style.:extension",
  :styles => {
    :original => '100x100',
    :thumb => '30x30'
}
```

initializers/paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip.interpolates :img_name do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.img_name
end
```

`img_name` is field populated in form on upload with the image.
The error I get on upload is:

> Invalid argument - (C:/Users/.../stream20110410-384-stl2lk20110230-213-1fm2bab, C:/.../photo_upload/public/images/:img_name-original.jpg)

Comment: Thank You! I moved from paperclip.rb to model and it works now...

Comment: I added it as an answer so that it's clear that it's an solution.

Answer (score 10):

Seems to work if it's directly in the model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  Paperclip.interpolates :img_name do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.img_name
  end

  has_attached_file :photo,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/images/:img_name-:style.:extension",
    :styles => {
      :original => '100x100',
      :thumb => '30x30'
    }

end
```