# Undefined method in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried to change the path for paperclips folder:

```
     has_attached_file :image,
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/#{self.patient}/:style/:filename",
    :styles => {.....
```

But somehow I get this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `patient' for #<Class:0x692c328>):
app/models/photo.rb:4:in `<class:Photo>'
app/models/photo.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/patients_controller.rb:24:in `show'
```

I dont undestand why, my full model code:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
    has_attached_file :image,
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/#{self.patient}/:style/:filename",
:styles => {
  :thumb    => ['100x100>',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
  :preview  => ['480x480>',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
},
:convert_options => {
  :thumb    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
  :preview  => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
}
   validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

   def patient
     self.patient.id
   end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/#{self.patient}/:style/:filename"
```

the code is extrapolating `#{self.patient}` at *declaration time*, not at runtime. Since at declaration time, `self` is of class `Class` you get an undefined method error.

I'm not sure it will work, but you might try:

```
:path => ":rails_root/public/system/:patient/:style/:filename"
```

Anyway, you could check this question: [Rails 3, Paperclip - Custom Interpolations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613456/rails-3-paperclip-custom-interpolations)

Comment: Ok i think i found a solution : http://viget.com/extend/paperclip-custom-interpolation